# ReportEvent - when should I close HANDLE?

Tags: c++

I've seen many examples of ReportEvent function on the web. In those examples, the handle  that is sent to ReportEvent (first argument) is created right before the call to ReportEvent and destroyed right after the call (with RegisterEventSource and DeregisterEventSource respectively).

Is there a reason why the HANDLE is alive only for a short time? Why would it be better than just creating the HANDLE in the begining of the porgram and destroying it at the end? (after all it's only one HANDLE and around 16 million is the maximum). Is there no overhead on creating and destroying the HANDLE each time we call ReportEvent?

Thanks in advance,

Dror

Comment: Code pls. I want to know how you create the handle.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Other than those pages simply also showing how to create and destroy the handle, this might be inspired by FUD about what happens when the program crashes without being able to call DeregisterEventSource().  With the assumption that the event wouldn't be logged, that would be bad of course.  Afaik, it is just FUD and not a real concern.  Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. At the beginning of wmain, you may do:

```
HEVENT hEventLog = RegisterEventSource(NULL, PROVIDER_NAME);
```

And, at the end, of wmain,

```
if (hEventLog)
    DeregisterEventSource(hEventLog);
```

This should do, and you may reuse same handle

Answer (score 0):

The more interesting aspect of this question is following - can we call RegisterEventSource only and then assume that *exiting process is enough to auto-close all related handles* including the one which was obtained via RegisterEventSource?

In other words - if we know for sure that process will be exited sometime then we can call RegisterEventSource only. Nothing more.

And even more clarifying form of the same question - if we will not call DeregisterEventSource() what problems that may cause? Would be there a kind of *internal leak* in whole OS? Or any other consequences?

For example: 
I need to call ReportEvent() in lot of different DLLs, as result - in every DLL I always have to call 3 functions: RegisterEventSource, ReportEvent, DeregisterEventSource. I would like to use internal static variable with a handle, call RegisterEventSource only once and then never call DeregisterEventSource with a hope that when process exited all related handles will be auto-closed. 
Would that work?